# recommendation for exercises/problem books

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I am studying

1.Multivariable Calculus - with emphasis on limits, continuity , differentiability of functions of two variables , maxima minima

2.Linera algebra -emphasis on questions of  dimensions, vector spaces , linear transformation , special matrices

3.Real analysis - Power series , Topology of real number line(limit points , connected sets , compactness , and related )

4.Group Theory only

In that background, I am looking for a problem book in a spirit somewhat similar to Problems in Mathematical Analysis by AMS so that I have a lot of problems to solve.i need book which contains tons of problems with varied difficulty. I need to focus on computational problems, based upon how to apply theorems to solve problems. I have already looked up related questions on this website, but rather looking for comprehensive list.

Thanks